# Why is a networking hub not secure? How can we make it secure?

Tags: network

The reason that a hub is not secure nor safe is that it copies the data to all the connected links, so it is enough for the adversary to connect to one of the links (reason 1)? Are there any other reasons?

If a hub is not secure, how can we make it secure? what are alternative secure solutions?

I know switch can choose the intended link, so it is more efficient, and thus it is harder for the adversary to attack. But,  the only concern for a hub's security is the reason 1 (mentioned above)?

This link says switch gives a better efficiency, they are not a replacement for  hubs for security purposes: [Hubs, Switches, and Bridges - Flaws and Security Superiority](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/hubs-switches-and-bridges-flaws-and-security-superiority)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a hub secure.  A hub, by definition, is always going to send the traffic everywhere.  The question you link to about switches is true, but a switch is still a necessary first step to adding the security you seek.  In the related question, Thomas Pornin points out that normal switches can be tricked in to sending information to the wrong place, but that is not true of all switches when properly configured.

Features such as VLANs and static routing can be configured to make sure that a router always knows exactly where traffic should go and won't go anywhere else.  It's important to understand the features of your particular router or switch to understand exactly how to configure connections.

You can't make a hub secure because it has no switching logic by definition.  A switch, on it's own, will make a best effort to figure out where to send information, but if it isn't configured with exact information, an attacker may be able to fool it.  A switch configured with exact routing information (at a port level) will obey the routing information and only send the information to the necessary ports.

If you really need to protect traffic and a hub or dynamically configured switch or router is in the network, you can instead just use an encrypted VPN to secure your data over an unsecured link.  At that point it doesn't matter if an attacker can get your data feed as they will be unable to read or alter it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a hub secure because it has no internal logic to change. It's a 'dumb' device that simply retransmits.

Switches and routers have internal logic, processes, and firmware/software that can be altered, configured, or upgraded to offer different features and functions.

Switches can end up acting like hubs in certain conditions, but they are the devices that make it possible to direct traffic more securely.